# Is this function casting safe?

Tags: c++, arduino

This is standard Arduino library. On line 92 https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-megaavr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.cpp the user supplied function `void(*)(void)` is cast into `void(*)(void *)`  (voidFuncPtrParam is `void(*)(void *)`)

How does this work? On line 138, the user supplied function is always called with a `void *` argument, regardless if it was `void(*)(void)` or `void(*)(void *)`. Can you even do this safely?

Comment: Casting via `void*` is safe, as both sides caller and callee agree about the type it's actually poining to. If any of the sites doesn't cast it back correclt, that would cause _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Concerning all the if-s and when-s (such a cast is safe or not), I came to the conclusion: Safe is to pass a pointer by its correct type, so that it's everywhere obvious what it really points to. Casting tricks aren't really safe concerning maintainability. (Though, I know as well the situations where this is the last resort while the actual fix would mean: Throw everything away and start new.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Well, depends on the definition of _safety_, right? _"Life isn't safe, and can't be made." - Elisha Otis_ ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this function casting safe?

The cast itself is always safe. You can always cast function pointer to any function type.

The call at [WInterrupts.cpp#L138)](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-megaavr/blob/master/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.cpp#L138) is indeed undefined behavior, as it calls `void (void)` function via `void (void*)` pointer.

> How does this work?

The code was written specifically for megaavr to be run on megaavr compiled with compiler for megaavr. Because of how [arguments are passed to functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Frame_Layout) additional arguments are just set up in register on caller side and just ignored on called side.

> Can you even do this safely?

Safe code would do a trampoline probably sacrificing performance.

```
static void trampoline_call_user_func(void *param) {
    // let's be super super safe and use memcpy instead of cast to void*
    void (*userFunc)(void);
    memcpy(&userFunc, &param, sizeof(fptr));
    userFunc();
}

void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, void (*userFunc)(void), PinStatus mode) {
   // let's be super super safe and use memcpy instead of cast to void*
   void *param;
   static_assert(sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(userFunc), "");
   memcpy(&param, &userFunc, sizeof(userFunc));

   attachInterruptParam(pin, trampoline_call_user_func, param, NULL);
}
```

but on any modern architecture just passing function pointer via `void*` "will work" (although a function pointer is not required to be able to cast to `void*`), just:

```
static void trampoline_call_user_func(void *param) {
    // let's be super super safe and use memcpy instead of cast to void*
    void (*userFunc)(void) = param;
    userFunc();
}

void attachInterrupt(uint8_t pin, void (*userFunc)(void), PinStatus mode) {
   attachInterruptParam(pin, trampoline_call_user_func, userFunc, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I use a union of void pointer and void returning nully function pointer to store maybe callbacks, because why not.